# accesing each index of matrix without indexing or using for/while loop

Tags: matlab

i need to write a function that takes in an argument n, and returns a n*n matrix with each entry as a function of i and j

For example i need a 2*2 entry with each entry abs(i-j), so the function should return the following matrix:
[0,1;-1,0]

Is there a way to do this without using for or while loops to individually assign each value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[i, j] = meshgrid(1:n);
out = abs(i - j);
```

*EDIT* As Dan points out, this results in `i` varying by column (i.e. each column of `i` has a constant value); and `j` varying by row (each row is constant). `ndgrid` orders the outputs the other way around.

Comment: I think you'd want `[j, i] = meshgrid(...` based on how matrices are usually indexed.

Comment: Dan's quite right - the syntax I've used there is more useful for 'x' and 'y' type stuff - so beware.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ndgrid`:

```
n = 2;
[I, J] = ndgrid(1:n, 1:n)

abs(I-J)
```